# MS office paste options getting disabled

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, copy-paste, paste

I am not sure what is causing this, but every time I restart my system, the paste options in MS office apps such as outlook and word get disabled. I also see that the value of PasteOptions in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\General` is set to 0 even after I manually set it to 1.

The only recent change that I performed was installing Grammarly. Has anyone else seen such an issue?

Is there any way to permanently enable it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grammarly extension is indeed known for this particularity.
Uninstalling it should fix the problem.

See user testimony at the post
[Show Paste Options button not staying checked](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/show-paste-options-button-not-staying-checked/232e4c10-d62e-4b70-acb9-befb3814e61e?auth=1&page=1),
where this was answered by user MattyDR, and his answer was then upvoted by
151 people up till today.

Comment: Oh, I had seen this thread but missed the comment. So no way to get around this? :/

Comment: You may complain to the Grammarly developers, or disable it and enable only when really needed.